# Reading a php session variable inside an html select tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to access a php session variable inside an html select tag, so I can use it to determine how to populate the options.

If I echo the variable outside the select tag, it works fine, but it will not echo inside the tag.

I don't have the experience to know why.

Below is a snippet of the code, I have removed the code that is not relevant, to make this easier to read.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['profile_type']='test';

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <title>Profile</title>
</head> 

<?php
  echo $_SESSION["profile_type"];  //This WILL echo.

?>

<select id="profile" name="profile">

<?php

    echo $_SESSION["profile_type"];  //This will NOT echo.

?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably echos out, but you can't see it unless you look at source.  Within a `<select>` field, you need to have `<option value='foo'>Foo Text</option>` lines.  The Option tags are what populate the select box.  The select box is what is sent with the option value upon submit.

Comment: I do have options in the full code, I don't think that's the issue. I need to be able to read this session variable to determine how to populate the options

Comment: Could you show your code based around that?  There could be a comparative syntax typo, or something else.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew already stated, whatever is inside a `<select>`-tag must be of type `<option>`. So for you to list the session-variable you're looking for, you'd need something like this

```
<select id="profile" name="profile">
    <option value="test">Text here</option>
    <?php
    echo "<option value=".$_SESSION['profile_type'].">".$_SESSION['profile_type']."</option>";
    ?>
</select>
```

Note that superglobals such as `$_SESSION`, `$_GET` and `$_POST` cannot be specified inside a string, and must be concatenated as above.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, sorry it took so long for the penny to drop.